# WordPress Image Replacement via Database

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, migration

I am currently undergoing the process of migrating a site from the old server to a new staging server. We are currently in the process of updating all image paths with new ones hosted in Amazon S3.

I have logged into phpMyAdmin and ran SQL statements to find and replace the old image path with the new ones in the *wp_posts* table. After running through a small set, we realized that the page was not reflecting the new image path.

What is going wrong and is this the best method to go about replacing the images? I have tried some plugins and ran into the same issues.

Site is using Elementor

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Elementor has its own tool to change the site's URL. I prefer [the CLI command](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/cli/replace-urls/), but there's also an [interface in the WP admin](https://elementor.com/help/will-elementor-work-if-i-change-the-domain-of-my-website/).

If old URLs continue to show, try running WP CLI's [`search-replace` command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) to make sure all URLs in the database were replaced.

Comment: I was using Elementor's Replace URL tool to replace the images but that was not successful either. It replaced the values in the wp_posts table that I was, yet the page would not reflect the updates.


Disabled cache and all, still no updates.

Comment: You may want to also try WP CLI's [`search-replace` command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/), to make sure you've found all URLs in the database.

Comment: I'll try that out Caleb, thank you. Will get back to you!

Comment: Installed WP CLI into the directory of the WordPress installation but it keeps referencing the following when running wp --info:

-bash: /usr/local/bin/wp: No such file or directory

I installed WP CLI in originally in /usr/local/bin but came with the following error after running the search-replace command:

Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress installation.
The used path is: /usr/local/bin/

Comment: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1661

Comment: Perfect, just needed to point via --path!

Comment: Ran the search-replace via WP CLI and still no avail. I am really baffled on why this is happening.

Comment: At this point I recommend creating an mu-plugin, which behind a gate prints out info for an image in the Media Library, and see if you get the correct URL or not. This may help rule out some things.